# Old Data, Old MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have been running MySQL 5.6.12 for awhile now. I decided to update my WAMP server to the latest PHP version.

In doing so, it also updated MySQL to 5.6.17, preserving .12 data, but that is inaccessible.

How can I access my MySQL .12 data? I have the `data` folder which includes the database I want. Which also has all the tables in a `.frm` and `.idb` formats.

Comment: I think you should Get old MySQL data from old mysql folder and import into new database

Comment: I have tried upgrading my mysql server before and didn't have any problem. Do you encounter any error?

Comment: @noobdeveloper no errors, It didn't migrate my data.

Comment: @OPatel Try to edit your my.cnf then point your datadir to the directory of your mysql .12

Comment: @noobdeveloper where can I find the .cnf? I've searched my computer for it and I can't find it.

Comment: You're using windows? In windows, the file is my.ini or my-default.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the old mysql-version too, make a dump (using mysqldump) and reload it into the new MySql- version.

Comment: I'm unable to access the data to make dumps. All my MySQL tools are using the latest version of MySQL on my computer.

Comment: Then try [mysql-upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html)

Answer (score 0):

First find the data directory via command:

```
show variables like '%datadir%'
```

It shows your current data directory and you can check is it new or old one.

Then find the my.cnf or my.ini file in your system.
Then change the line containing datadir='' to your data folder and restart the folder.